# float buffer casting to unsigned char* losing data on socket send

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, casting, network-programming

Is there a better way to send float data over a socket? 
Below is an implementation that sends the data.

```
static float theOUTPUT[THE_FLOAT_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE];
int size = 2048;
int tb = 0;
int numbytes = 0;
int cs = 256;
unsigned char* buf = (unsigned char*)theOUTPUT;
while(tb < size) {
    numbytes = send(sock, buf, cs, 0);
    printf("bytes sent: %i\n", numbytes);
    tb+=numbytes;
    buf+=numbytes;
    if(tb >= size) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the type and value of `ch`?

Comment: is there a reason you are converting the array into an unsigned char* array?

Comment: int ch =1;  Yes I am casting the float buffer to unsigned char* to send it over the network.

Comment: I suggest you post a complete example that still exhibits the problem (though you might just find your error in the process of producing one :)

Comment: You've set `size` to 2048.  Is there a reason for this?  Shouldn't it be something like `sizeof(theOUTPUT)`?

Comment: If this is going from one computer to another, realize that even if both server and client are using C, no specific float internal representation is guaranteed by the C standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.  It was not a very good question. I discovered the issue and found that I was sending more data than I thought over the socket. This what was corrupting the data.

@user470379
C programming language standard is unrelated to floats but I think that is what you mean.
If you build the server and the client then you have control over how you encode your data regardless of the programming language.

Answer (score 0):

In this code, there's no guarantee that `size` matches `sizeof(theOUTPUT)`. If it less, then you will lose data.